# iPhone core data problem : referenceData64 only defined for abstract class

Tags: iphone, xml, core-data

I have an application that downloads/parses a big XML file and store the information using core data (approx. 4000 objects (entities)).
The XML is loaded/parsed in a different thread, which has its own NSManagedObjectContext.

When trying to save the entities to the persistent store, I sometimes get the following error (about 20%)

2010-03-03 23:41:42.802 xxx[7487:4203] Exception in XML saving
2010-03-03 23:41:42.802 xxx[7487:4203] Description: *** -_referenceData64 only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSTemporaryObjectID_default _referenceData64]!

2010-03-03 23:41:42.803 xxx[7487:4203] Name: NSInvalidArgumentException

2010-03-03 23:41:42.804 xxx[7487:4203] UserInfo: (null)

2010-03-03 23:41:42.805 xxx[7487:4203] Reason: *** -_referenceData64 only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSTemporaryObjectID_default _referenceData64]!

I have a simple integer to keep track of the entities the application creates compared to the insertedObjects property in the NSManagedObjectContext before saving, and when I get the error, these numbers do not match, insertedObjects in the NSManagedObjectContext is missing about 10 entities.

I do not know how I should continue to investigate this problem, anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Thanks
/oscar

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with core data and multithreading operations.
Read this [article](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMultiThreading.html) for understanding of the problem.

In the working thread I began to use the functions **lock, unlock** for NSManagedObjectContext and crash not repeat any more.

Comment: Subcategory *subcategory = (Subcategory *)[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:currentSubcategory.objectID];

That solved the issue for me.

Comment: the article link is broken.

Comment: Your solution works for me. Personally I was iterating ALAssetsLibrary using blocks. Inside each block I was writing to CD. I encapsulated the block content in @syncrhonized( <my ALAsset* from the block params>) and it works great now. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: Your solution is actually different that what I just said. You are referring to -(void)lock and -(void)unlock in the NSManagedObjectContext class as to where I was talking about a synchronize block which does not lock the object context.

Comment: I'm guessing the article Victor wanted to link to was this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385

Comment: @fzwo, that article link is also broken

Comment: Apple is not very good at permalinks for their docs. Moved here, I guess: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you use custom NSManagedObject subclasses for your entities? This problem can occur if you do incorrect initializations etc. in `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`